How to make adaptive GridItem to fill in whole width with small number of items
I need to show 2-3 items horizontally if screen width allows and vertically otherwise.
I thought adaptive GridItem would do the trick. It works well for portrait mode, however it doesn't fill up available space in landscape mode.
Code:
struct MyView: View {
    private let columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 200)),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, content: {
                ForEach(1...2, id: \.self) { item in
                    Color.red
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

See how it thinks it could fit a third item on landscape mode so it reserves space and doesn't use the whole space for just 2 items:


The solution for the problem is to use an environment value to check for current vertical size class, can be accessed next way:
@Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var vSizeClass

And switch between predefined arrays of columns that you want to use in specific cases.
The whole code would look:
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var vSizeClass
    
    private let regularVerticalColumns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 200))
    ]
    
    private let compactVerticalColumns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 200)),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 200))
        // * In case you need more than two items placed horizontally 
        // you could add additional grid items here
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            // Switching between columns
            LazyVGrid(columns: vSizeClass == .regular ? regularVerticalColumns : compactVerticalColumns, content: {
                ForEach(1...2, id: \.self) { item in
                    Color.red
                        .frame(height: 100)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}


Note: that you can add more grid items in compactVerticalColumns, to increase an amount of horizontally aligned items in landscape mode.
